# Get the data after selected two strings in one line (filename.txt)

Tags: awk, sed

**output requirements:-**

I want to extract the data after 33A::ISN and need to extract the price after 16E:AVVV//FMMM/.

16E:AVVV//FMMM/ is always succeeding after 33A::ISN.

The code has to fetch the data after 33A::ISN and extract the price after 16E:AVVV//FMMM/ and print the data in one line.

Next succeeding value after 33A::ISN and price after 16E:AVVV//FMMM/ should print in line 2 and similarly for next lines

***Input data:-***

11A::Aqty//PRCE/666,5000

11B::SUB//VEND

11c::ASD//FSE/890,

33A::ISN USDFG238

//instrument charaterted

34A::PRIC//VEND,

16E:AVVV//FMMM/7890,

19A:HGLP//USD

33A::ISN SECFG238

//inst EWQW

16E:AVVV//FMMM/9890,

19A:HGLP//HUT

33A::ISN ERWQWW8

//iCHAR HAT

16E:AVVV//FMMM/134000,

19A:HGLP//POT

***output:
*
***output the data with delimiter separator.*****

USDFG238,7890

SECFG238,9890

ERWQWW8,134000

****what i have tried****

i have tried awk and sed commands. i need to get the output in linux

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Do we need to loop to get the output

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
11A::Aqty//PRCE/666,5000

11B::SUB//VEND

11c::ASD//FSE/890,

33A::ISN USDFG238

//instrument charaterted

34A::PRIC//VEND,

16E:AVVV//FMMM/7890,

19A:HGLP//USD

33A::ISN SECFG238

//inst EWQW

16E:AVVV//FMMM/9890,

19A:HGLP//HUT

33A::ISN ERWQWW8

//iCHAR HAT

16E:AVVV//FMMM/134000,

19A:HGLP//POT
```

then

```
awk 'index($0,"33A::ISN "){printf "%s,",substr($0,10)}index($0,"16E:AVVV//FMMM/"){print substr($0,16,length-16)}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
USDFG238,7890
SECFG238,9890
ERWQWW8,134000
```

Explanation: I use [String Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), `index` function to detect lines containing `33A::ISN`  and lines containing `16E:AVVV//FMMM/` I do that rather than using regular expression to avoid problems arising due to `/` which has special meaning. For lines which have `33A::ISN`  I use `substr` function to get everything beyond it and then use `printf` with value being followed by comma. `printf` does not append ORS (newline by default) unlike `print`, for lines containing `16E:AVVV//FMMM/` I `print` (so there will be newline) everything beyond it and before last characters, `length` is length of whole line (number of characters) which I use to compute length of substring I need.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: I have tried the above command but it is not working